# Turn on a trickle of water from faucets

Tags: grammar

[Source](https://www.mlive.com/news/kalamazoo/2023/02/spoiled-food-fleeing-homes-kalamazoo-residents-make-tough-choices-in-ice-storm-aftermath.html)

> She planned to head back to her home Friday afternoon to check on it, and to **turn on a trickle of water from faucets** so the pipes don’t freeze.

---

Does "**from faucets**" modify "**a trickle of water**" or "**turn on**"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It modifies "a trickle of water." To see why, remove "a trickle of water" from the sentence:

> She planned to head back to her home Friday afternoon to check on it, and to **turn on from faucets** so the pipes don’t freeze.

You can't turn on *from* faucets, you can only turn on faucets. The preposition "from" doesn't make sense if "from faucets" is modifying "turn on."

Answer (score 2):

It could be either.

Syntactically, we cannot distinguish. For example:

> He drank some water from the spring behind the house.

could mean that he drank directly from the spring, or that he had a glass of water from the spring and drank that.

We generally rely on semantics to distinguish (and sometimes the result is genuinely ambiguous). But in your case here there is no practical difference.

Comment: I think the water companies in the UK would be up in arms if they thought customers were *deliberately* running dripping taps to guard against pipes freezing up! A few years ago I had a little-used WC that unbeknown to me was continuously overflowing a trickle down the waste pipe. I was quite shocked to see just how much my water bill reduced by, after the faulty shut-off valve was identified and fixed.

Comment: Well, that's all right, because we don't have "faucets" to turn on or not!